# Cast a date in English into a value of type "date"?

Tags: mysql, date, casting

Please suggest how I can transform the string `"12 march 2004"` into a value with date data type.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: select cast('12 march 2004' as date);
- Does not work.
   select cast('120412' as date);
- not a good solution, i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. It takes two arguments: the input string and a format specifier string.

For your example you could use the following:

```
STR_TO_DATE("12 march 2004", "%e %M %Y")
```

For the table of format specifiers go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Is there any other way to do it ? Maybe without str_to_date() function ?

Comment: Well, if this query is being run through some programming language then you can always manipulate it there.

Comment: It works. But I was curious to know if there are more ways of doing this without this function.